# como paso un fecha en formato text a formato DATE con sql

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una tabla llamada venta en donde tengo un campo que guarda la fecha DD/MM/AAAA el tipo de este campo es text ahora q necesito realizar filtros con esa fecha he tenido problemas con consulta bien la información, segun entiendo lo idea es que ese campo estuviera como DATE.

Me gustaria conocer cual es la forma ideal de poder pasar este campo a DATE y poner el formato correcto AAAA-MM-DD
no se si se pueda actualizar el mismo campo a crear otro campo llamado venta_at en donde se guarde la fecha con el formato DATE.

buscando encontre algo similar

https://blog.open-office.es/base/convertir-campo-de-fecha-tipo-varchar-a-date

````
UPDATE "venta" SET "venta.venta_fecha" = 
  CAST( SUBSTRING ( "venta_at", 7, 4 ) ¦¦ '-' ¦¦ 
        SUBSTRING ( "venta_at", 4, 2 ) ¦¦ '-' ¦¦ 
        SUBSTRING ( "venta_at", 1, 2 )  
           AS DATE)
```
al ejecutar esto me arroja un error

> Error
Existe la posibilidad que usted haya encontrado un error en el intérprete de SQL. Examine cuidadosamente su consulta y verifique que las comillas están siendo usadas adecuadamente y hacen juego. Otra posible causa del fallo es que esté subiendo un archivo con datos binarios por fuera del área de texto delimitado con comillas. Intente su consulta en la interfaz de comandos de MySQL. La salida generada por el servidor de MySQL, de existir, aparece abajo y puede ayudar a diagnosticar el problema. Si aún tiene problemas o el intérprete falla en tanto que en la interfaz de órdenes funciona, reduzca la salida de su consulta de SQL a la consulta que genera el problema y envíe un reporte de error con la cadena de datos en la sección de CORTE indicada abajo:
----INICIO DEL CORTE----
eNqlj01OwzAQhfc+xVvRVnKtxLhtZMTCTa0UKX/YDtsqqoJg0woIIC7Ug/RkOLWqdseCWYzm530z
etqYykikMVKOXJcSSYyEg0ecWOc3xwMhxY99zCVmbMYEJ401qCyFynTpKJ60VxXtFunaVIX2PIuY
iIRg8W1C6kJJCOabiNTrelDTyg635n6EVfv+/bojuSozie6DnP409Uo5jZu3z31/99Xt+jaUsNpd
T9kpb5677ctZcQ8CpMq6MWyz9AYeygzja2jT9qGjWFAITLzD4wGj6SgUng/xNy8o+H/4OPAXxIey
GMxPfgGXcnGg
----FIN DEL CORTE----
----INICIO DEL VOLCADO----
ERROR: C1 C2 LEN: 81 82 202
STR: ¦

MySQL: 5.5.42
USR OS, AGENT, VER: Mac CHROME 81.0.4044.138
PMA: 4.4.10
PHP VER,OS: 5.6.10 Darwin
LANG: es
SQL: UPDATE "venta" SET "venta.venta_fecha" = 
  CAST( SUBSTRING ( "venta_at", 7, 4 ) ¦¦ '-' ¦¦ 
        SUBSTRING ( "venta_at", 4, 2 ) ¦¦ '-' ¦¦ 
        SUBSTRING ( "venta_at", 1, 2 )  
           AS DATE)
----FIN DEL VOLCADO----
Existe la posibilidad que usted haya encontrado un error en el intérprete de SQL. Examine cuidadosamente su consulta y verifique que las comillas están siendo usadas adecuadamente y hacen juego. Otra posible causa del fallo es que esté subiendo un archivo con datos binarios por fuera del área de texto delimitado con comillas. Intente su consulta en la interfaz de comandos de MySQL. La salida generada por el servidor de MySQL, de existir, aparece abajo y puede ayudar a diagnosticar el problema. Si aún tiene problemas o el intérprete falla en tanto que en la interfaz de órdenes funciona, reduzca la salida de su consulta de SQL a la consulta que genera el problema y envíe un reporte de error con la cadena de datos en la sección de CORTE indicada abajo:
----INICIO DEL CORTE----
eNqlj01OwzAQhfc+xVvRVnKtxLhtZMTCTa0UKX/YDtsqqoJg0woIIC7Ug/RkOLWqdseCWYzm530z
etqYykikMVKOXJcSSYyEg0ecWOc3xwMhxY99zCVmbMYEJ401qCyFynTpKJ60VxXtFunaVIX2PIuY
iIRg8W1C6kJJCOabiNTrelDTyg635n6EVfv+/bojuSozie6DnP409Uo5jZu3z31/99Xt+jaUsNpd
T9kpb5677ctZcQ8CpMq6MWyz9AYeygzja2jT9qGjWFAITLzD4wGj6SgUng/xNy8o+H/4OPAXxIey
GMxPfgGXcnGg
----FIN DEL CORTE----
----INICIO DEL VOLCADO----
ERROR: C1 C2 LEN: 81 82 202
STR: ¦

MySQL: 5.5.42
USR OS, AGENT, VER: Mac CHROME 81.0.4044.138
PMA: 4.4.10
PHP VER,OS: 5.6.10 Darwin
LANG: es
SQL: UPDATE "venta" SET "venta.venta_fecha" = 
  CAST( SUBSTRING ( "venta_at", 7, 4 ) ¦¦ '-' ¦¦ 
        SUBSTRING ( "venta_at", 4, 2 ) ¦¦ '-' ¦¦ 
        SUBSTRING ( "venta_at", 1, 2 )  
           AS DATE)
----FIN DEL VOLCADO----

consulta SQL:

UPDATE "venta" SET "venta.venta_fecha" = CAST( SUBSTRING ( "venta_at", 7, 4 ) ¦¦ '-' ¦¦ SUBSTRING ( "venta_at", 4, 2 ) ¦¦ '-' ¦¦ SUBSTRING ( "venta_at", 1, 2 ) AS DATE)

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"venta" SET "venta.venta_fecha" =
  CAST( SUBSTRING ( "venta_at", 7, 4 ) Â¦Â¦ ' at line 1

> Cita en bloque

gracias
````

Comment: En general es muy mala idea guardar valores de fecha en columnas `VARCHAR`. Dentro de lo posible cámbia la columna a `DATE`.

Answer (score 0):

debes usar algo asi:

```
CONVERT(data_type(length), expression, style)
```

donde:

data_type: 8
expression --> tu cadena string.
style: 101  --> mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `STR_TO_DATE()`, los parametros que recibe son la fecha y luego especificas el formato en el que viene dicha fecha, el resultado sera una fecha valida para MySQL. En tu caso seria algo asi:

```
STR_TO_DATE('01/10/2020','%d/%m/%Y')
```

y el resultado sera este:

[image: Resultado]